# Creating byte buffers in rust

Tags: buffer, rust, slice, mutable

What is the most efficient way to get access to `&mut [u8]`? Right now I'm borrowing from a Vec but it would be easier to just allocate the buffer more directly.

The best I can do right now is to preallocate a vector then push out its length but there is no way this is idiomatic.

```
    let mut points_buf : Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(points.len() * point::POINT_SIZE);
    for _ in (0..points_buf.capacity()) {
        points_buf.push(0);
    }
    file.read(&mut points_buf[..]).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just create the vec with a given size directly:

```rust
vec![0; num_points]
```

Or use iterators:

```
repeat(0).take(num_points).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

Comment: My concern is with reallocations. How can I find out if the `vec!` macro does a `with_capacity`?